# Laravel Broadcasting не возвращает результатов

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь создать real-time уведомления используя Laravel Echo и Pusher, но не получаю никаких результатов. Пользуюсь своим authentication middleware-ом, поэтому изменил файл **BroadcastServiceProvider.php** файл, передал атрибут, как указан в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-routes). Ниже мои файлы и код.

**FriendRequest Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Users;
use App\Friend_requests;

class FriendRequest implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('notification');
    }
}
```

**routes/channels.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('notification', function($user){
     return true;
});
```

**app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['authorized']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,
});

window.Echo.private('notification')
    .listen("FriendRequest", (e)=>{
        console.log(e);
    });

    console.log("Laravel Echo");
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', "UserController@test");
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function test(){
        broadcast(new FriendRequest("Some text"));
    }
```

**config/broadcasting.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: В .env файле установили BROADCAST_DRIVER на pusher? Там же прописали PUSHER_ настройки для Пушера? Также учтите что у вас указана middleware для broadcasting’а как authorized, т.е пользователь должен быть авторизирован при GET запросе на /test

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да, установил. BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Поздно заметил Ваши изменения. Попробовал - не работает.

Comment: Посмотрите консоль браузера, подключается ли вообще к пушеру. Мб какие ошибки выдает.

Comment: @Pavel до создания PrivateChannel, я получал данные от Pusher. В консоле ошибок нет.

Comment: @Narek выходит сам коннект работает. Совет банальный, но попробуйте без мидлвара своего. Просто судя по вашим файлам - у вас всё дефолтное.

Comment: @Pavel Без middleware'а выдает ошибку 403 (Forbidden)
**POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)**

Comment: @Narek минимум проблема в вашем мидлваре, пробуйте пока без него. гулите теперь 403, может какие настройки на стороне пушера еще.

Comment: @Pavel Хорошо, спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Narek  например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643417/post-http-localhost8000-broadcasting-auth-403-forbidden  и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728930/laravel-broadcasting-auth-always-fails-with-403-error